# Will DBCC IndexDefrag Works in SQL SERVER 2005?

Tags: sql-server

I have a script (taken from web) that loops through all tables in my db and defrags the indexes. I'm using the following code for this:

```
USE mydb

DECLARE @TableName sysname  
DECLARE @indid int  
DECLARE cur_tblfetch CURSOR FOR
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table'  

OPEN cur_tblfetch  
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_tblfetch INTO @TableName  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   DECLARE cur_indfetch CURSOR FOR  
   SELECT indid FROM sysindexes
   WHERE id = OBJECT_ID (@TableName) and keycnt > 0

   OPEN cur_indfetch  
   FETCH NEXT FROM cur_indfetch INTO @indid  
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
   BEGIN  
      SELECT 'Derfagmenting index_id = '
              + convert(char(3), @indid)
              + 'of the '  
              + rtrim(@TableName)
              + ' table'  
      IF @indid <> 255 DBCC INDEXDEFRAG (mydb, @TableName, @indid)  
      FETCH NEXT FROM cur_indfetch INTO @indid
   END 

   CLOSE cur_indfetch  
   DEALLOCATE cur_indfetch  
   FETCH NEXT FROM cur_tblfetch INTO @TableName  
END

CLOSE cur_tblfetch  
DEALLOCATE cur_tblfetch
```

When I run it I get multiple errors like:

> Msg 7999, Level 16, State 41, Line 18 Could not find any index named
>   '_WA_Sys_00000003_3BFFE745' for table 'mytable'

.

My sql server version: SQL Server 2005. In few web sources, it shows DBCC IndexDefrag doesn't work. Is that true? Is there any alternative? Please advise it's a production need

Comment: Given that there's [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177571(v=sql.90).aspx) for it, specifically for 2005, what other "web sources" are you looking at? But also, why do you ignore that even on the 2005 documentation, you're told to stop using it?

Comment: That name looks like a statistic not an index

Comment: You'll find many articles online explaining that religiously defragging indexes is a bit of a waste of time

Comment: Hi Nick, Could you please explain why defragging is waste of time? It would really help me provide a justification to the client to disable it